# Creating professional GUI for Android application

Tags: android, user-interface

I want to create professional looking GUI for Android application. Something more than just raw widgets which I'm taught to use in countless tutorials in the web.
Unfortunately, I couldn't find any source of information how to customize those widgets and create better looking GUI.
Examples could be: http://android.appstorm.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/calorific-sc.jpg
or http://android.appstorm.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/chomp-sc.jpg

How are such GUIs created? If you could point me out to some tutorials on it, I would be really thankful!

Greetings,
Bart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing in those examples that looks like it couldn't be made from standard components. For instance the second screen of that calorific application is just a background image for the window with a list and a button with a background image as well. The first image could easily be done with just buttons and background images for views as well.

**TLDR:** Split the view into rectangles, assume that these are all standard components with images as backgrounds unless they seem to have nonstandard interactions.

Comment: so, based on what you've written, it's more customizing built-in components than creating custom components. Good to know, however, if anyone happened to know some tutorials about such customization (I believe there is more possibilities than just setting the background), please post it here. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Those are called custom components.

You will need to do  a fair amount of work to get the look you want. (compared to using system components).

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html

**Edit**
Bone up on your Google-fu Bart!

http://www.google.com/search?q=custom+components+android+tutorial

Comment: Custom components are more necessary for behavioral/layout calculation changes or really nonstandard drawing where you would need direct canvas access. I don't think custom components are really necessary here